# bashの「レントジョブ」とは何を意味するのでしょうか

Tags: bash

bashでジョブについて勉強中です。`help` コマンドでは下記のように出ますが、

```
$ help fg
fg: fg [job_spec]
ジョブをフォアグランドにします。

JOB_SPEC で識別されたジョブをフォアグランドにして、現在のジョブにします。
もし JOB_SPEC が存在しない場合、シェルが現在のレントジョブとして考えている
ものが利用されます。

(以下省略)
```

文中の「レントジョブ」という用語がわかりません。ネット検索しても出てきません。どなたか意味を教えていただけないでしょうか。

bashのバージョンは GNU bash, バージョン 5.0.3(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) です。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ LC_ALL=C help fg
```

とすると英語でヘルプが表示されますが、これによると

> If JOB_SPEC is not present, the shell's notion of the current job is used.

となっていますのでオイラ流に翻訳すると「シェルがカレントジョブと思っているものが使われます」となり、単純に翻訳の際の誤記ですね。 s/レント/カレント/